# python3 2d dimension list editing problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
apple_emoji = ""
white_square_emoji = "⬜"
space_block = "  "

def main():
    running = True
    apple_location = (random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10))
    location_list = [[space_block]*10]*10
    location_list = location_list.copy()
    location_list[1][1] = apple_emoji
    print(location_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want it to be output like

```
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
```

but in fact it output like

```
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
```

I also tried to soft copy it but it didn't work.
The only method useful is to use

```
location_list = [['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']]
```

Comment: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178)

Comment: Replace `location_list = [[space_block]*10]*10` with `location_list = [[[space_block] for i in range(10)] for x in range(10) ]`